# Grails insert date without time

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have a date attribute in my domain and I want to insert to MySQL without time. getting exception  cannot cast string to `date.Exception` message:

> Cannot cast object 2013-03-09 with class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date

I want to insert to the database without time.

Domain:

```
class Day {

    
Date date
    
        static mappings = {
        table name:'Days'
   
              date type: 'date'
         
         
    }
```

Controller:

```
def today = new Date()
def ymdFmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
Date dateYmd = ymdFmt.format(today) 



        day.date =dateYmd
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856545/grails-illegal-arguments-for-java-sql-date .

Comment: When inserted in database it's 2013-03-09 00:00:00 I don't want 00:00:00

Comment: Then use `DATE` type in database, not `DATETIME`.

Comment: I have use DATE. See my mapping in domain class But time still appearing

Comment: @ user903772: Oh, I see. I believe date variable should be   `java.sql.Date` that doesn't have time portion,not just `Date` (which turns to be `java.util.Date`)

Comment: @user903772: I believe that the type in your database is not DATE, but DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. The mapping on domain class only means for Hibernate to read, not exactly what will be generated at DB level. You should check at DB level

Comment: @user903772 Please refer to the docs to see the differences of these data types http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wan't to look at `Date.parse` http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

You can parse the date like.

```
String stringDate = '28/09/2010'
Date date = new Date().parse('d/M/yyyy', stringDate)
```

Comment: When inserted in database it's 2013-03-09 00:00:00 I don't want 00:00:00

Comment: Don't know if there is a way around it. But it basically doesn't matter since you could just ignore the time. It's just a minor detail.

Comment: Surely it does matter..? Typically for a webapp, a date (e.g. 2013-03-09) will be persisted as UTC. If that date is then read by my application and display to users in UTC-1 and UTC+1 timezones, they will see the date as 2013-03-08 and 2013-03-09 respectively.

Comment: The issue is not about storing 0s for the time, is about having a column type in the database that is 'date' and not 'datetime', in other words the time shouldn't be stored at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
day.date = new Date().clearTime()
```

clearTime() will reset the time portion to 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

You should use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

The `java.sql.Date` class corresponds to SQL `DATE` which means it stores years, months and days while hour, minute, second and millisecond are ignored. Additionally `java.sql.Date` isn't tied to timezones.

For a good explanation about the two see [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)